# mysql search where column like ''

Tags: mysql

Quick questions, I bet the answer is so simple and I am just being blind. 
I want to select from the database all the names that only start with "test_1_1_".

I would guess that I do this with;

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE names LIKE "test_1_1_%";
```

This doesn't seem to work. 
The results keep showing up as

```
test_1_1_1
test_1_1_2
test_1_11_1
test_1_11_2
test_1_12_1
test_1_12_2
```

How can I select with MySQL only the results that start with "test_1_1_"?

Thank you in advance.

Wesley

Answer (score 1):

Underscore has a special meaning in `LIKE` and needs to be escaped:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE names LIKE 'test\_1\_1\_%';
```

You could also use `REGEXP` here, and avoid the escaping problem:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE names REGEXP '^test_1_1_';
```

Comment: That was indeed the problem! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `_` inside `LIKE`, it will mean replace that space with any character.

For example, searching for something like `field LIKE 'a_'` will result in any `field` with 2 characters starting with "a".

If you really want to search for the underscore characters, you need to escape the value with `\` and your query will look like this: `LIKE 'test\_1\_1\_%';`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen damn.. you're fast

Comment: Can we use *damn* in this case?

Comment: @lucumt If there are any problem with this word I can delete the comment. English is not my first language and the comment was supposed to be funny.

Answer (score 0):

Can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE names LIKE "test\_1\_\1\_%";
```

Answer (score 0):

The underscore is a single character wildcard when use with LIKE. So to specifically locate an underscore it needs to be "escaped" as follows:

```
select
*
from mytable
where names like 'test\_1\_1\_%' escape '\'
```

> To test for literal instances of a wildcard character, precede it by
>   the escape character. If you do not specify the ESCAPE character, \ is
>   assumed.
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html